# How to compare two array values in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, compare, array-merge

i have two functions, the first one is:

```
   public function computeGHComponents()
    {
      error_reporting (E_ALL^ E_NOTICE);          

      $totals = NULL;

      foreach ($this->transaction as $t){

          $amount = (float) $t['Amount'];



            if (isset($totals[ $t['SiteID'] ][ $t['TransactionType'] ])){
                $totals[ $t['SiteID'] ][ $t['TransactionType'] ] += (float) $amount;
            } else {
                $totals[ $t['SiteID'] ][ $t['TransactionType'] ] = (float) $amount;
            }
        }

     foreach($totals as $key => $value)

        {

         $this->result[$key]['Deposit'] = isset($value['D']) ? $value['D'] : 0;
         $this->result[$key]['Reload']  = isset($value['R']) ? $value['R'] : 0; 
         $this->result[$key]['Redemption'] = isset($value['W']) ? $value['W'] : 0;

       }
    echo "<pre>";

  print_r($this->result);

}
```

and the second function is:

```
    public function bindOwnerToSites(){

     error_reporting (E_ALL^ E_NOTICE);  

    foreach( $this->balance as $keysaa =>$key_valuesa)//getsitebalance
            { 
                foreach( $this->sites as $keys=>$key_values)//getsites
                  {

                        if  ($key_values['SiteID'] == $key_valuesa['SiteID'])
                        {

                         $this->arrays[$key_valuesa['SiteID']] = array('SiteID'=>$key_valuesa['SiteID'],'Balance'=>$key_valuesa['Balance'],'MinBalance'=>$key_valuesa['MinBalance'],'MaxBalance'=>$key_valuesa['MaxBalance'],'OwnerAID'=>$key_values['OwnerAID'],'GroupID'=>1);    

                        }
                 }

            }
       print_r ($this->arrays,$return=null);  
    }
```

Now I need to compare both SiteID in order to bind and here's my function:

```
    public function bindGHComponentsToSites()
    {
    error_reporting (E_ALL^ E_NOTICE);  


     foreach ($this->arrays as $keys => $data) {

        foreach($this->result as $key => $value){


    if ($data['SiteID'] == $value['SiteID']){
            }
     }
 }
```

I used to echo the comparing of SiteID, like this:

echo($data['SiteID'] .'=='. $value['SiteID']);

but there's no value in $value['SiteID'] from the function of computeGHComponents(), it shows like this:

```
 2==
 2==
 2==
 3==
 3==
 3==
```

how can I get the value of SiteID from computeGHComponents()? Please help me to modify my codes. Thank you in advance.

Comment: variable scope issue by the looks of it. http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: @ Dagon, how can I modify my codes using of that? Thank you so much.

Comment: You'll have to use `print_r` or `var_dump` to show us the content to both arrays, otherwise there's no way we can guess the structure...

Comment: I already used the print_r and echo to test my arrays, but I can get the value of SiteID of ComputeGHComponents(). Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

I used to print_r my $keyss and I found out that it was the SiteID so I modify my code like this:

```
    public function bindGHComponentsToSites()
    {
   error_reporting (E_ALL^ E_NOTICE);  


     foreach ($this->arrays as $keys => $data) {


       foreach($this->result as $keyss => $value){

         //print_r($keyss );echo '<br/>';

         if($data['SiteID'] == $keyss){

               //statement...
            }
       }
    }
```